# Is it possible to localize Freeform fields and labels?

Tags: localization, multi-site, plugin-freeform, freeform

Is it possible to localize labels and other params of Freeform form fields on the multilingual site? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can render the fields by your own and use the twig translate filter and do it with translation files. But I think there is no way to do it via the CP currently.